# Ubuntu System-Wide Proxy Auto-Configuration (PAC) script

Tags: ubuntu, proxy

I am using Ubuntu via VirtualBox. I need to set proxy auto-configuration script. It works in FireFox but the global preferences-->network has no effect. So when I do "apt-get install" it is not able to download anything.

How can I tell the entire Ubuntu system that I want it to use the specified PAC file to configure proxy settings for any app that needs to connect to the internet?

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get install
```

doesn't do any installation , the correct syntax is:

```
apt-get install package_name
```

But did you see the output of that program in terminal ?

And setting proxy in firefox won't affect a global proxy settings , you may need to refer to Network Manager in Ubuntu.

@update:

the whole progress will be involved , e.g when install mscorettf-installer with wget

```
%> cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/00proxy 
Acquire {
    Retries "0";
    HTTP {
        Proxy "http://221.176.168.178:80";
    };
};
```

Comment: I used the full syntax. The terminal days it needs to download something but is stack at 0% probably since there is no network. What is Network Manager? I have opened preferences-->network in the ubuntu desktop and set the proxy script but this has no affect.

Comment: see my update , i resolved this.

Comment: This is not system-wide.

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the environment variable

```
export http_proxy=http://ip.addr.of.proxy:port
```

then enjoy your apt-get

Comment: how do I configure proxy configuration script (pac)?

Comment: Too hard for the command line environment, I think.

Comment: But you can try to get a copy of that pac file, it's JavaScript, easy to understand. Then you can set the "http_proxy" accordingly.

Comment: this pac is highly complex and changes often. I need to configure it directly. it does not make any sense not to be able to do it, there is a ui option for it (which does not work) and every corporate needs it

Comment: This would only work if 1. The PAC script simply told us to use a single proxy for everything, always and 2. The PAC script never changed.